# Replace OAuth2 client provder properties in Spring Boot for testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Our Spring Boot application acts as an OAuth2 client and, by default, contacts the identity provider's (here: Keycloak) endpoint for its "OAuth Well-Known Configuration Information" configured by this Spring property:

`spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri`

The problem is, that any `@SpringBootTest` then also attempts to connect to such a server which fails immediately. So, for integration testing, I'd like to replace the above `issuer-uri` with the propeties `jwk-set-uri`, `authorization-uri` and `token-uri` which don't prevent the application from starting.

So, I created the following `application.yml` which does its job but I think it's not very obvious for other team members what happens here.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: ${app.authentication.client-id}
            client-secret: ${app.authentication.client-secret}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak"
            scope: openid
        provider:
          keycloak:
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: default
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${app.authentication.server-url}

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: integration-test
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            jwk-set-uri: ${app.authentication.server-url}
            authorizationUri: ${app.authentication.server-url}
            tokenUri: ${app.authentication.server-url}
```

Is there soem other apporach how to diable the `issuer-uri` and replace it by the three above properties when testing?

Comment: What is the scope of your "integration testing" exactly? If limited to a controller, then it's unit testing and you'd netter use @WebMvcTest. Else why isn't test authorization-server available (like in a docker conatiner or something)?

Comment: Did you find a better solution, Robert? I could only slightly improve on your solution to use "!integration-test" as profile to make sure the issuer-uri is always set in non-test envs, even when my application may have other profiles in production env. Yours is the only workable solution I have found so far. I also opened an issue with Spring Boot to address this problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33848.

Comment: Oh well, someone else already posted that exact issue on there and it got declined: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28139. null value support is pending (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24133) but has not moved since 2020.

Comment: @MarkusRohlof Unfortunately, I couldn't follow up on the issue for a longer time. It will become relevant again for our project soon, so I guess I will then reevaluate it.